# Machine learning for portfolio optimization

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, machine-learning

What algorithms from machine learning, supervised learning or unsupervised learning have been recently used for asset allocation models as alternatives to the Markowitz mean-variance optimization model? So far I only know of

- Clustering using [hierarchical risk parity model](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2708678) which won the author quant of the year at the *Journal of Portfolio Management*

Comment: He wrote a book that's pretty well done.  Prob a good place to start.

Comment: The references cited in the paper can be used to find related works in that topic I think.

Comment: not really. clustering is an *unsupervised* learning model, whereas random forests and support vector machines are *supervised* learning algorithms. even though i know SVMs are popular in industry, there are no well-known publications on how to apply them to portfolio construction